# Get and set Token in Nuxt 3 application

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt, nuxt.js, token

im making a login request, that in the backend returns a token in the Cookies section in insomnia, the only response is the JWT token

[image]

how can i get this user by making the login request in my frontend? the request is working in the frontend, but when i try to access the token, it returns undefined

```
  let response = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/client/login', {
                    email: this.login.email,
                    password: this.login.password
                })

                const token = await response.data.cookie
                if (process.client) {
                    window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                }
```

by default, nuxt 3 dont allow localstorage, but with this if i think that the problem is get the token by itself, but im not sure

UPADTE: this is my response:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I recomended to use localstorage by that way:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    saveData() {
      localStorage.setItem('yourKey', 'yourValue');
    }
  }
```

Or u can use cookies by that way:

1. You have to install `cookie-universal-nuxt` via npm or yarn

```
npm install cookie-universal-nuxt
```

2. Register the plugin in your Nuxt 3 project. Open the `nuxt.config.js` file and add the following code:

```
export default {
  // Other Nuxt.js configuration options

  plugins: [
    'cookie-universal-nuxt'
  ]
};
```

3. Access the Cookies using the `$cookies` object in your Vue components:

```
<script>
export default {
 methods: {
   saveData() {
     this.$cookies.set('myKey', 'myValue');
   }
 }
};
</script>
```

More info to use `cookie-universal-nuxt` link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt